# Prove that $\sin^2(x)/x=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ has infinite solutions

Tags: calculus

I am trying to prove that 
$\sin^2(x)/x=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ has infinite solutions.

I know that $\sin^2(x) $is between [0,1] and $|x|>|\sin(x)|$ therefore $x>\sin^2x$
so the left side of the equation is between [0,1]. 
for right side of the equation I know that it between [0,1) but I don`t know how to continue from these info in order to show that it has infinite solutions.

Also, I am thinking the Intermediate value theorem might help to prove it, however I don`t know how to show more than one solution with this theorem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is the right idea.  Note that the left-hand side is $0$ at multiple of $\pi$ and the right-hand side is $0$ at the integers.

Comment: What you probably want to do is to show that you have at least one solution in an interval $(k\pi,(k+1)\pi)$

Comment: What is $[x]$ ?

Comment: @RhysHughes [x] is Nearest integer function which returns the nearest integer to x. For ex. x=1.25 it returns 1.
for x=-1.75 it returns -2.

Comment: \lfloor and \rfloor. If I misinterpreted, please fix my edits

Comment: @Andrei how can I show that I have **at least one**? 
with intermediate value theorem I can show only one solution between the interval (kπ,(k+1)π)? Am I wrong?

Comment: @JohnD The intermediate value theorem guarantees you *at least one* solution, not *only one*.

Comment: @JohnD How about for $1.75$, is $[1.75] = 2$?

Comment: @AlexVong for [1.75] it returns 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive integers $n$

On every interval $(n, n+1]$

$\frac{\sin^2 x}{x} - x + \lfloor x \rfloor$ is continuous.

$\lim_\limits{x\to n^+} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x} - x + \lfloor x \rfloor > 0$

and

$\frac{\sin^2 (n+1)}{n} - n + \lfloor n \rfloor < 0$

Answer (score 0):

It is not restrictive to look for solutions $>1$.

Consider
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin^2x}{x}-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)
$$
Then, for integer $n>1$,
$$
f(n)=\frac{\sin^2n}{n}>0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to (n+1)^-}f(x)=\frac{\sin^2n}{n}-1<0
$$